# Webpack 4 exclude entry from output hashing

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've the following webpack 4 configuration for production:

```
entry: {
    app: './src/js/app',
    'font-awesome': './src/js/plugins/font-awesome',
    '../install/install': './src/js/installation/index',
},

output: {
   path: path.join(__dirname, './production/public'),
   filename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js'
},
```

I want to exclude *install* from the output hashing process, but i can't find a way. Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. It looks like [output.filename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename) can be a function. I solded with the following code:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './production/public'),
    filename: function(data) {
        return data.chunk.name === '../install/install' ? 'js/[name].js' : 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js';
    },
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js'
},
```